# Dynamically define variable names

Tags: python

I have written some classes I would like to test by creating multiple instances of my classes. I would like those instances to have names following the pattern `p1`, `p2`, etc:

```
p1 = Point(1,1)
p2 = Point(2,2)
p3 = Point(3,3)
```

Is there a way to do this quickly for a lot of variables? Something like this:

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    *magic goes here*
isinstance(p500, Point) # True
```

Comment: [Don't do that](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html), either use a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the current scope changing `globals()`

For instance:

```
globals()['p234'] = Point(1, 2)
print p234
```

This is however, **an extremely poor quality approach**: hard to understand, maintain, creates a horrible scope polution and it is slow (although this does not probably matter). Use a proper data container, I would suggest a list:

```
points = [Point(i, i) for i in xrange(500)]
assert isinstance(p[-1], Point)
```

This way you can do an assert on every object like:

```
points = [Point(i, i) for i in xrange(500)]
for point in points:
    assert isinstance(point, Point)
```

Comment: For a simple case like this, I would not recommend mucking with `globals()` or `locals()`.  Just use a list.

Comment: But if you do that, you are using your variables namespace as if it were itself a variable. This usually leads to regret later on.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer to my actual question, however, the better way to do what I'm trying to do is probably to use a list as suggested by RemcGerlich.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich This answers the question, and it is interesting to know that you can modify the current lexical scope dynamically. However, as I stated in the answer, it is a very poor solution.

Answer (score 6):

It's called a list:

```
p = [Point(1, 1), Point(2, 2), Point(3, 3)]
```

Now `p[0]` is your `p1`, et cetera.

```
p = [Point(i, i) for i in range(1, 1000)]
isinstance(p[500], Point)  # True
```

Answer (score 1):

you could store them as keys in a dictionary

```
vars_dict = {}
for i in range(1,1000):
    vars_dict['p{}'.format(i)] = Point(i, i)
isinstance(vars_dict['p500'], Point) # True
```

or in an iterable as @RemcoGerlich did

Comment: I suppose that might be easier.